# How many row level locks can I have to same row?

Tags: postgresql, locking

I need some insights on **row-level** locking in **Postgres**.

1. How many shared locks (FOR SHARE) can be concurrently on a particular tuple in a relation .
2. Will have many shared locks on same tuple cause any performance/or any issue to database.
3. If such limitations exist, how to configure them and advisable limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html#LOCKING-ROWS)

> PostgreSQL doesn't remember any information about modified rows in memory, **so there is no limit on the number of rows locked at one time**. However, locking a row might cause a disk write, e.g., SELECT FOR UPDATE modifies selected rows to mark them locked, and so will result in disk writes

<sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

So the only performance issue that you might get, is the number of disk writes heavy locking might cause.

---

While there is an "unlimited" number of row locks in the system, there is a limit on the number of objects (e.g. tables) that can participate in locking for a single transaction, which is controlled through [max_locks_per_transaction](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-locks.html#GUC-MAX-LOCKS-PER-TRANSACTION)

That property controls the number of *objects* one transaction can hold locks for, not the number of locks. A transaction can lock a million rows in a single table. However the default value of 64 for `max_locks_per_transaction` means that a transaction can hold locks for at most 64 *tables* (but e.g. a million rows in each table). So if your transactions never touch more than 64 tables, there is nothing to worry about.

A common reason to increase this value is if you are dropping a lot of tables in a single transaction e.g. through a [`drop owned by current_user`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-drop-owned.html) statement to clean up a database.

Comment: Supposed that `BEGIN; select for update 1 million;  END`, could you explain about `locking a row might cause a disk write`? Does it write to WAL or disk ? Does it write to temporary file before `end transaction` ?

Comment: The OP asks about shared locks, ie. "SELECT FOR SHARE".  See the paragraph just before your quote.

Comment: Sorry, because I was curious about "quote from the manual".